# django - Generate multiple PDF files in a loop condition using reportlab

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab

I am in a django project and trying to generate multiple PDF files in a loop condition using reportlab.

view.py

```
def pdftest(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for x in range(0, 3):
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
            buffer = BytesIO()
            doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=portrait(letter))
            elements = []
            ptext = 'Hellow World! --- %s' %x
            styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
            elements.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles['Normal']))
            doc.build(elements)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format('test.pdf')
            pdf = buffer.getvalue()
            buffer.close()
            response.write(pdf)
            return response
    context = {}
    context['title'] = 'PDF TEST'
    return render(request, 'companies/pdftest.html', context)
```

But my program produce only one PDF. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: You’re returning your response in the first pass through the loop (`return response`). What do you expect happens after `return`?

Answer (score 0):

You’re calling `return response` in the first pass of your loop so obviously your program never reaches the second or third pass.

Comment: I know that is the problem. But when I call 'return response' out of the loop, it still produced only one PDF.

Comment: Think about it: if you call `return response` after the loop you’re only returning the last `response`. Every time through the loop you’re reassigning a new PDF to `response` and loosing the previous one. You should save it somewhere to disk I guess if you want to access the PDF later. What are you trying to do? Return 3 files in one response? Then add the files to a `response` object created outside of the loop. And which client is going to consume the response, a browser can’t get 3 files to download at once. That’s not possible.

Comment: I think you pointed out exactly where I am wandering about. As you mentioned, saving pdf files somewhere to disk and accessing them later should be better. I will try in that way. If you could introduce any good reference, it will be much helpful.

Comment: Check the Django documentation on [FileStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/storage/) and File to see how to handle files.